# Inbuilt feature of puppet Enterprose

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Is there any built in feature of Puppet Enterprise that we can use to have a push based mechanism, Apart from Mcollective and Bolt.

Comment: There is only: MCollective (to be retired), Bolt, and Puppet masterless (not a product by itself, but you use a cron job that does `git pull` to get the latest modules and run puppet apply).

Comment: PE Orchestrator is what you are looking for: https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2018.1/orchestrating_puppet_and_tasks.html. You can reach out to Puppet for these kinds of questions though, as they will be best equipped to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by 'push based' you mean triggering Puppet Agent runs, you can trigger a run in the PE console directly, or (as you mentioned) use Bolt in the PE console to run Puppet as part of a 'plan' or 'task'